TCP Window Size
Based on this thread, I'd like to ask a follow-on question..
What-is-a-tcp-window-update
Can an MTU mismatch cause this type of behavior as well? It would make sense to me that it could.
SRC:9000 -> SRC_WAN:1500 -> DEST_WAN:1500 -> DEST:9000
We are seeing lots of TCP Window Updates on the links and discovered the above MTU mismatch

No it can’t. Only reading by the receiver can cause it.

Regularly updating the window is nothing inherently bad, so why do you seem to worry about this?

This is a storage replication circuit and the vendor has said they are seeing too many of these as well as too many resends. We are also seeing lots of replication data backup into cache.

Ask the vendor to define ‘too many’.
